# How to update context menu already displayed with TrackPopupMenu in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, drop-down-menu

Say, if I display a popup context menu using TrackPopupMenu() API with TPM_RETURNCMD flag. While the context menu is displayed I need to see if Shift or Ctrl key is pressed on the keyboard and depending on that update some menu items from the context menu. Is that possible?

Comment: You should check the key and make your changes before you call TrackPopupMenu. Changing a menu while it is being displayed is not something users expect.

Comment: Let me say that I'm a big fan of your articles, Raymond. In despite of that I disagree with you. It is counter-intuitive to expect users to press a key before the menu is actually shown. Anyone who used Mac OS X or most of the Adobe products will agree with me. BTW, any way you can write an article on this subject? Please post a link here if you do. I'm sure many people would like to learn the right way of doing this...

Comment: The right way of doing it is not to do it. Windows has established the convention that menus do not change while they are being displayed.

Comment: Is there a record of this in Microsoft's version of "Human Interface Guidelines" for Windows?

Comment: If you look around the system, you'll see that absolutely zero apps do this, so it's not something that users expect. That's why I described it as a convention and not a rule. If you do it, none of your users will understand it since no other apps work this way.

Comment: Barring the UX consistency question: you could use a listview control instead of a menu - it's some effort to make it look like a native menu, but "close enough" though - but maybe that's not even required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard user experience for the platform that you're developing on. I know that I would be annoyed by such behavior. It is standard on the Windows platform to press the meta key before opening the menu. For example, holding shift while right-clicking an item in Explorer provides a modified context menu (e.g., "Open with..." or "Open in new process").

**Follow the platform conventions.** I don't expect an application on a Mac to behave like one on Windows and I don't expect an application on Windows to behave like one on a Mac. If you don't respect the conventions, you risk a large community of annoyed users.  [See Lotus Notes, SAP]

Answer (score 2):

You have to call something to modify menu item like `::SetMenuItemInfo()` then call  `::DrawMenuBar()` to redraw it.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I call it from? The function returns only when a user chooses an item in it.

Comment: Yes, but notification messages still work. So you have to do it in menu notification handler of hWnd that you gave to `TrackPopupMenu()` to receive notifications.

Comment: What "menu notification handler" are you referring to?

Comment: Something like WM_MENUCHAR, i am not exactly sure.

Comment: DrawMenuBar() redraws the window menu (the menu bar on top of it), it doesn't affect popup menus.

Comment: DrawMenuBar() allowed me to draw immediate update. Thank you, racked my head on this one.